# Setting the Font for an Excel sheet using C#

Tags: c#, excel, fonts

How can I set the font of an Excel Sheet in C# WITHOUT using spire.xls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can use the Excel Interop to do so. Add the reference to your project and away you go. The rest is creating an instance of the application, adding a workbook, then a worksheet and then setting the font of a range.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you don't have the interop, you can grab it from MS.

Comment: ok yes I got it. I was setting the property of FontStyle instead of Name. Thanks